# rotate google ads after load

Tags: javascript, adsense

Is it possible to show multiple google ads after the page loads? By multiple, I mean different add units?

so for example the page loads with

```
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-0005161421666";
google_ad_slot = "181834236";
```

and 5 minutes later i want to replace all ads with ads from a different client id?

I tried changing those on the page and re-requesting the google ads async loader but that does not seem to want to load the new ads. Any thoughts? Google terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that it is against Google AdSense policy to rotate ads, it inflates your page load count; some of their providers pay on a CPM basis.

Comment: as nice as it was of you to remind / highlight mkoryak of Google's policies, the question wasn't Does Google policy allow you to rotate ads, rather how to do it. If you don't know please refrain from answering next time.